# Replace Column value in dataframe -1 with 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

I have a columns in pandas dataframe that has multiple values like -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1.........-1 around 1000. What i want is to convert those -1 with 0. so it shows like 0 0 0 0 0 0 ....0000

```
df_img_attr_label = pd.read_csv(r'D:\DeepFashion\Category and Attribute Prediction\list_attr_img.txt',names = ['Image_Name'],header = None)
df_img_attr_label[['Image_Name', 'attribute_label']] = df_img_attr_label["Image_Name"].str.split(" ", 1, expand=True)
df_img_attr_label["attribute_label"] = df_img_attr_label["attribute_label"]

ret_rows = df_img_attr_label.loc[0:1000,:]


df_2 = ret_rows.replace([-1, 0])
```

I want column values -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1...to be 0 0 0 0 0......

Answer (score 1):

could be similar to Yasir suggestion but without quotes

```
df_2 = df_2.replace(-1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Try this:

```py
df_2 = df_2.replace('-1', '0')
```

Comment: I have  but it is not working because column has like multiple -1 in a long string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pandas`'s `Series.map` method

```py
s = df['col_to_be_mapped']
df['col_to_be_mapped'] = s.map(lambda x: 0) # if all values are -1

# if there are other values also you can use this function
df['col_to_be_mapped'] = s.map(lambda x: 0 if x == -1 else 1)
```